# Django Rest Framework with Social Auth And Request Post (CSRF-Security)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-csrf

i need help with Django Rest and Social Auth.... I have one view with the next structure...

```
class ObtainAuthTokenFacebook(APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, backend):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        user = register_by_access_token(request, backend)
```

And this is me fucntion to login....

```
from django.contrib.auth import login


@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
    access_token = request.data.get('token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(access_token)

    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return user
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

when in my view a send the response.... my front end recieve this...

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2015 18:53:31 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.9
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=PZHraHwhFsog2eT6n5psckJBfFEPmPQR; expires=Fri, 05-Aug-2016 18:53:31 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:  sessionid=nhxbh9slhw3pw887necskqfohczkzxo3; expires=Fri, 21-Aug-2015 18:53:31 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

But.... i this moments i working with ios and ios save the cookies of the first request... , and when i send the same request the cookies paste in my headers .... the server respond with one 403....This is because the code have structure like this, where my request send the csrftoken and one sessionid..
[image]

And when the request arrive to the server , this refuse this request...

How i manager the csrf token in my backend....to avoid reject future requests.....

Answer (score 0):

django-restframework uses django's built-in CSRF protection mechanisms and does not implement its own. You *may* want to disable CSRF for your api endpoints so that any client can POST/PUT/PATCH to them. You can do this in two ways:

a) System-wide by removing `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from your list of middlewares

b) Selectively, by decorating your endpoints with [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt). For decorating CBVs methods class-wide, you need to use the [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) decorator on the `dispatch` method.

This way, clients of your API don't need to worry about a csrf token.

Whatever you choose to do from the above, I reccomend that you first read the docs on CSRF in django so that you are aware of the implications of disabling this protection in any part of your application: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/

If this works for your application needs, then you're good to go :)

Comment: But... if i implement that mecanism of csrf ..... because ,,, every time i send i request with one csrf... the request is refuse?....That part of me is not clear.....

Comment: details of how CSRF is implemented in django can be found here: http://git.io/vOhCT but from what I could see, in you iOS app you were trying to reuse a csrf token generated somewhere else (probably on your borwser?), which will not work on clients other than the one it was generated for

Comment: This csrf did generated when i send the first request to the server.... then.. this csrf saved in the device... 
then.. when i send other request to this server..this token go in the headers... in this moment i dont know beacuse the request is refused if i implemnte this mecanism of csrf in miy backend...Tanks for your help....

Comment: my backend generates the token but it rejects later.